# How can I set auto increment id(s) for each table in a sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite, sequence, auto-increment

I'm using sqlite as a datbase for my application, each table has a primary key auto increment not null, I add a client in clients table and it gets 1 as an id, i add another one and it gets 2, and then when i try to insert into article table (which has no relation with client table) I get number 3 as an id for the row I inserted, Sqlite also creates a table named SEQUENCE which stores the highest value among the ids of all the tables.
What should i do to auto increment ids for each table separately ( unless there are dependencies of course ) ?

Comment: Autoincrement IDs *are* separate.

Comment: I know they normally are, but not in my case where every new row takes SEQ_COUNT column value +1 as an id ( SEQ_COUNT exists in a table named SEQUENCE generated automatically).

Comment: That are not the names used by SQLite's internal autoincrement mechanis. If your application implements its own autoincrement mechanism, then you have to look there.

Comment: No my application does not implement its own autoincrement mechanism, I had no such problems when I've been using mysql and postgres with the very same application which I've been working on for more than a year now, I switched to Sqlite for portability reasons, thank you though !

Comment: Is the name really `SEQUENCE`, not `sqlite_sequence`?

Comment: In fact both are present, SEQUENCE contains one row where the highest value among all tables IDs is stored, sqlite_sequence as you probably know contains stores the highest value of each table ID, I solved the problem by disabling autoincrement in all the tables and setting IDs values via Java program. Thank you for your answers mate